# Interceptor call ordering in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What is the default order of intercpetor call in spring framework if there are more than one  interceptor defined .Do we need to implement Ordered interface of spring framework for ordering of interceptor call?If Ordered interface is not implemented how it handles the ordering .If it is implemented from which class in framework it is controlled?For example there are 5 interceptor for login,privilage,cache,security,dynamic operation before calling a actual method in ....package.class.methodName.

Here it is xml

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="interceptor1" ref="beanId">
            <aop:pointcut id="pointcut" expression="execution(* *..*ServiceImpl.*(..))" />
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="pointcut" method="someMethod" />
            <aop:after pointcut-ref="pointcut" method="someMethod1" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
    <bean id="beanId" class="className">

    </bean>
```

Comment: How did you register your interceptors?

Comment: I have used xml to define it.

Comment: Could you please post that